# Statsmodels logistic regression convergence problems

Tags: numpy, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a logistic regression in statsmodels on a large design matrix (~200 columns). The features include a number of interactions, categorical features and semi-sparse (70%) integer features. Although my design matrix is not *actually* ill-conditioned, it seems to be somewhat close (according to `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`, it is full-rank with `tol=1e-3` but not with `tol=1e-2`). As a result, I'm struggling to get logistic regression to converge with any of the methods in statsmodels. Here's what I've tried so far:

- `method='newton'`: Did not converge after 1000 iterations; raised a singular matrix `LinAlgError` while trying to invert the Hessian.
- `method='bfgs'`: Warned of possible precision loss. Claimed convergence after 0 iterations, obviously had not actually converged.
- `method='nm'`: Claimed that it had converged, but model had a negative pseudo-R-squared and many coefficients were still zero (and very different from values they had converged to with better-conditioned submodels). I tried cranking down `xtol` to `1e-8` to no avail.
- `fit_regularized(method='l1')`: reported `Inequality constraints incompatible    (Exit mode 4)`. Then raised a singular matrix `LinAlgError` while trying to compute the restricted Hessian inverse.

Comment: Can you share your data somewhere?

Comment: Alas, no; it's proprietary.

Comment: I found that standardizing the data helped with the convergence issues. This is an ok solution; I can't use formulas with it (because centering each column in the formula is a pain) and it makes the coefficients harder to interpret, but it at least gets it to converge.

Comment: The above "solution" also still failed when I added an 18-level categorical feature. There's some chance that this was due to actual collinearity, although I doubt it. I'll try to create example (random) data that exhibits the problem tomorrow.

Comment: Not wholly surprised. We have some code to do this internally but it's not hooked up by default yet.

Comment: Ah, excellent! That would make life a lot easier. Thanks for your excellent work on statsmodels--I know I'm asking a lot of it!

Comment: Do you use the parameters of the smaller model as starting values for the larger model when you add variables/terms?

Comment: It would be helpful if you have a ready example that fails and standardization makes it work. We could add it to the documentation.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with publicly-available code and data. I didn't get all the way there in the time I allotted, but I at least managed to reproduce some of the parts of it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1439158/Statsmodels%20test%20case.ipynb). Namely, I found that when using a spline basis the matrix appeared to be full-rank only for very low tolerances, and that logistic regression appeared to converge but gave meaningless confidence intervals and p-values. However, standardization didn't make this one work any better.

Comment: [A similar question in Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/463324/110833)